# Find function - error 91

Tags: excel, vba, find

I use this code to find for certain value in a range. This works fine if the searched value is of single digit or text. I get "error 91 Object variable or with block not set" whenever the searched value is of two digits. Could anyone tell what is wrong?
To make things clear I have uploaded the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nkja2xumcyap73/Find%20error%2091%20for%20double%20digits.xlsm
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Dim search_range As Range
Dim search_start As Range
Dim search_value As Range

Set search_range = shDaten.Range("E1:T1")
Set search_start = shDaten.Range("E1")

Set search_value = search_range.Find(What:=shSchl.Range("D25").Value, After:=search_start, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Which line throws the error? Have you tried to debug-step through code?

Comment: @mehow sorry for not being clear. I have updated my problem description. Yes, I have try to go throught the debug stepthrough. What I am wondering is why the code works when the find target is of single digit or of text.

Comment: As it is a bit complicated to explain my situation in words, I have uploaded my Excel file. Anyone who is willing to help please have a look at the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdkwgcqpckzeqxs/Find%20error%2091.xlsm

Comment: there is no `OptionButton_11_spalte2` in the uploaded spreadsheet

Comment: my bad - i clicked on the green button in sheet("Typenschluessel") and all empty rows are hidden and correspond OptionButtons are set to have height of 0.
I have uploaded the unhide version. Same download link works. thanks in advance!

Comment: @mehow OK, now i got you. I have simplified my file to only having three workable OptionButton (OptionButton_2_spalte2, OptionButton_3_spalte2 and OptionButton_4_spalte2). Please refer to the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Error found! The cells that contain the searched value must be formated as "text" (by right click on the cells/range and go to "format cell" and select "text").